# Is there a spin speed at which a magnet sheds its magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, centripetal-force, space

I was watching a video by Anton Petrov about Earth's magnetic field creating a space hurricane and am now wondering at what speed would a magnet have to be spinning in a vacuum to shed its magnetic field, if at all. Thanks for any answers. :)

Comment: Had you had any physics courses you would know that the magnetic field of a magnet is  due to  the solid lattice of atoms and molecules, and cannot be "shed"..

Comment: Wow, who crapped in your cheerios this morning? Thanks for the answer though.